# Save text file contents as an image

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am trying to convert the contents of a text file to an image using C#, but I cannot seem to do it. I get the annoying `A generic error occurred in GDI+.` error from `System.Drawing`.

Here is my actual code:

```
public static Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize, Color bgcolor, Color fcolor, int width, int Height)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, Height);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        Font font = new Font(fontname, fontsize);
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), 0, 0);
        graphics.Flush();
        font.Dispose();
        graphics.Dispose();
    }
    bmp.Save("C:\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");
    Convert(bmp);
    return bmp;
}
```

So at the line `bmp.Save("C:\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");` when I try to save the image, it brings this error. I read posts and similar questions and wrapped everything around a `using` statement as suggested at multiple sources, but I am still missing something and cannot figure it out.

I use the `File.ReadAllText(path);` to read the contents of the text file and then I make a normal call to my method:

```
ConvertTextToImage(content, "Bookman Old Style", 10, Color.White, Color.Black, width, height);
```

Comment: You are possibly getting that error due to trying to save to the root directory of C:. Try to change the file path in the Save() method to something like C:\Temp\<filename>.bmp. This has to do with the permission/UAC not allowing you to write directly to the root directory

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same generic error ... I also tried saving into the project's current directory - same thing. I think the location is not the cause here.

Comment: I just tested your code. Writing to C:\ throws the generic error, writing to C:\Temp\ was successful. Your code works as is.

Comment: You might want to use ToString("N") to get rid of the hypens in the filename.

Comment: @lapadets try it on another computer with "run as admin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to UAC, your are getting the generic error because you are trying to write to the root directory of the C: drive, which is not allowed in Windows.

Changing the line

```
bmp.Save("C:\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");
```

to

```
bmp.Save("C:\\Temp\\" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");
```

(or any other folder that you have permissions for), allows the successful creation of the image.

Comment: Yes, turns out I needed to run VS as an Administrator... I tried writing to another folder on `C:\`, but that did not work as well, so I initially discarded the rights idea.

Comment: I would advice against running VS as admin. Rather write to the AppData folder for temporary storage or another pre-defined folder, depending on what the application does with the image. Your users might not always have the rights to run the application as Admin

Answer (score 3):

So, you're `Dispose()`ing your `Graphics` object twice. Once via your line that says `graphics.Dispose()` and once that is done automatically via the `using` construct.  You should be fine with the method written as such:

```
public static Bitmap ConvertTextToImage(string txt, string fontname, int fontsize, Color bgcolor, Color fcolor, int width, int Height)
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(width, Height);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (var font = new Font(fontname, fontsize))
    {
        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bgcolor), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        graphics.DrawString(txt, font, new SolidBrush(fcolor), 0, 0);
    }

    bmp.Save("C:\\" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".bmp");
    Convert(bmp);
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: it seems that your change does not address the original error?

Comment: but double-disposing should not end up in an error, especially not in an GDI+-Error? It would then be a NullRef...

Comment: Yes, that's not addressing the question, but it is still valuable input :) thanks for the improvement. The error is UAC related - turns out I needed to run VS as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your app has no permission to write files on C:/. A have modified your code and this works for me:

```
bmp.Save(Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".bmp");
```

It will save the image in your app folder.

Moreover, you don't have to call `graphics.Dispose();`, because `using` does it for you.